# How to check if button has clicked run this else this?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I checked all the methods, didn't worked!
  I want to check when the `Button` is clicked set text to "Good" else 
  set the text to "Jump".

and is this possible? 
  The `Button` text it "Jump" and when clicked set to "Good"
  else reset the text to original without using `setText` again?

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(b.isSelected()){

            b.setText("Good");
            }
            else
                b.setText("Jump");  

        }
    });
```

Comment: Which type has your button b ?

Comment: its Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.Id.button2);

Comment: First get your Button's id like this
 Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

 btn.setText("Jump");

then set on click listener 
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
  btn.setText("GOOD");
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html), the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) event it returns has ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP states/actions which correspond to when the button was pressed and released respectively.

You set the listener like you set the onclicklistener:

```
myButton.setOnTouchListener(this); // Assuming you implement the listener interface in the same class.
```

Your OnTouchListener method would look something like this:

```
onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){ 
  if(v.getId() == R.id.myButtonId){
     if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
       // TODO change button text to "good"
     }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
       // TODO change button text to "jump"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what i'm talking about!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (button.getText().toString().equals("Jump")) {
                    button.setText("Good");
                } else {
                    button.setText("Jump");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean mClicked=false;
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
            mClicked=!mClicked;
            if(mClicked)
            {
            b.setText("Good");
            }
            else
            {
                b.setText("Jump");
            }  

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code -

```
String text="Jump"
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View view) {
                 text="Good";  
                 b.setText(text);
  }
 });
```